# .NET Session State Caching with Redis, MongoDB, ServiceStack

Tags: mongodb, redis, servicestack, distributed-caching

I have been doing some research on whether it is ok or not to cache .NET Session State in external Dbs such as Redis, MongoDb, or other highly scalable tools.

The output of my research was that even though MongoDB has more integration to do this kind of things, it seems that Redis is far more performant and has way more options (key expiration, sets, etc) to use.

There is this other framework called [ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack) which has an implementation of a RedisClient but IMHO the way it is implemented is far more coupled than I would like to.

```
 public override object OnGet(CachedOrders request)
    {
        var cacheKey = "some_unique_key_for_order";
        return base.RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(this.CacheClient, cacheKey, () =>
            {
                    //This delegate will be executed if the cache doesn't have an item
                    //with the provided key

                //Return here your response DTO
                //It will be cached automatically
            });
    }
```

So after this research, I would like to know your opinion and whether you have implemented this kind of caching in any of your apps. Can you please share you experiences?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

[ServiceStack's](http://www.servicestack.net) caching isn't coupled, the `ToOptimizedResultUsingCache()` method is just a [convenience Extension method](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/ServiceHost/RequestContextExtensions.cs) allowing you implement a common caching pattern in the minimal boilerplate necessary. The `ToOptimizedResult` method returns the most optimized result based on the MimeType and CompressionType from the IRequestContext. e.g. in a JSON service it would normally be the deflate'd output of the JSON Response DTO.

You don't have to use the extension method and can access the [ICacheClient API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/CacheAccess/ICacheClient.cs) directly as it's an auto-wired property in the `ServiceBase` class. If you require more functionality than the ICacheClient API can provide, I recommend using [Redis](http://redis.io/) and [ServiceStack's C# RedisClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) which gives you fast, atomic access to distributed comp-sci collections.

The benefit of using an `ICacheClient` API is that it's a testable implementation agnostic caching interface that currently has [InMemory, Redis and Memcached providers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a NuGet package for this 2 years ago, and we've been using it in production since then. It overrides the .NET `SessionStateProvider` with a custom class that allows persistence to Redis, with various features like:

- Only write to Redis on values changing
- Concurrent session access from multiple requests with the same session ID
- Ability to access the session from Web API (although doing so violates REST principles, if you care)
- Easy customization of serialization format (roll your own or change Json structure)

You can get it here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/RedisSessionProvider

Docs: https://github.com/welegan/RedisSessionProvider